# Is okhttp4 ready for Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile?

Tags: kotlin, okhttp, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

Instead of using e.g. `ktor` with `okhttp` as engine, could one directly use `okhttp4` as it's build only in Kotlin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OkHttp 5.x targets Kotlin Multiplatform. But multiplatform capabilities will be quite limited in the initial release.